# Retain Fragments through NavigationDrawer changes

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have my navigation drawer set up just like the one in the android developers [training](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).
Inside the navigation drawer i have two fragments right now. One of the fragments contains a listview, whose content is populated through an AsyncTask, which loads the items through a rather time consuming file system search. I already achieved to retain my list items through a configuration change:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState == null) {
        new LoadPdfList().execute(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    } else {
        pdfThumbs = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("pdfThumbs");
    }
}
```

But there is still one big problem, which i can't get solved. As soon as i switch my current Fragment with the navigation drawer and switch back to my previous fragment, which hosts the listview, the asynctask is reexecuted.
Although this behavior is not really surprising to me considering this part of the displayView-Code from the android developer tutorial:

```
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment newFragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        newFragment = new DocumentsFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        newFragment = new PlayerFragment();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    if (newFragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, newFragment).commit();
        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        currentFragmentId = position;
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

I tried messing around with the different possibilities from the transactionmanager but still couldn't get it running.
I just want my fragments being retained while changing the my fragments through the navigation drawer.

Comment: In what way is it not running? Are you getting an error? If so, please post the error information.

Comment: I am not getting an error. But my DocumentsFragment is completely reloaded with the savedInstanceState Bundle being null. I can say that because my Asynctask is executed again, which only happens in the if statement in my onCreate method. So my code is running but the list items are reloaded everytime i enter the fragment.